# How to use the express response.send in callback functions (used by mysqljs in nodejs for example)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express and mysqljs in express.If i request my database to add a user,i have to define a callback function to handle response. Unfortunately i have no access to express res.send in callback function.I want to send insertID to the res.send method.How i do this?. Here is my code.

```
app.post("/adduser", (req, res) => {
  const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "customer"
  });
  const name = req.body.name;
  const age = req.body.age;

const users = { name: name, age: age };
  const query = "INSERT INTO users SET ?";
  con.query(query, users, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Last insert ID:", res.insertId);
    // want to send res.insertId to server
    // res.send() here
  });

});
```

Comment: res.send( res.insertId); ?

Comment: I guess you are using the same variable name 'res' for both 'response' and 'result'.

Comment: @UsmanRana not working either

Comment: @naota also tried changing the name of the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the same variable name 'res' for both 'response' and 'result'.

AS the documentation says, con.query returns 'result' not 'res'.
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries

```
app.post("/adduser", (req, res) => {
    const con = mysql.createConnection({
          host: "localhost",
          user: "root",
          password: "",
          database: "customer"
    });
    const name = req.body.name;
    const age = req.body.age;

    const users = { name: name, age: age };
    const query = "INSERT INTO users SET ?";
    con.query(query, users, (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Last insert ID:", result.insertId);
      // want to send result.insertId to server
      // res.send() here

      // res.send(result.insertId); // gives an error
      res.send(result.insertId.toString());
    });

});
```

Comment: performing above steps give express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) error

Comment: @Nikhil, ok thanks. How about res.send(result.insertId.toString()); ?

Comment: i tried res.send({ id: result.insertId }) and toString() also work fine.
Thnx for help

Comment: @Nikhil, you're welcome. I'm happy if you accept my answer :-)